# Minimizing $L^p$ distance of a random variable and a constant

Tags: optimization, expected-value

Let $X$ be a real-valued random variable. Then expected value $\mathbb{E}[X]$ is the number $c$ minimizing $c \mapsto \mathbb{E}[(X-c)^2]$.
Similarly, the median of $X$ is the number $c$ minimizing $c \mapsto \mathbb{E}[|X-c|]$.

My question is what the numbers minimizing
$$c \mapsto \mathbb{E}[|X-c|^p]$$
are called for fixed $1 \leq p \leq \infty$ (assuming $X \in L^p$; for $p = \infty$ this is to be understood as in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space), whether these numbers are studied and whether they are unique.

My guess would be that for $p = \infty$, that number is the mean of the essential supremum and essential infimum
$$c = \frac{\text{ess sup}(X) - \text{ess inf}(X)}{2}.$$

Comment: The best-known terms are *median* ($p=1$), *mean* ($p=2$), and *midrange* ($p=\infty$). Using these as keywords, I found this Wikipedia entry on "generalized means:" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean#Generalized_means.

Comment: That seems not to be quite what the OP asks, since it does not ever give the median.

Comment: The linked article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_tendency answered all of my questions. Thanks!